# automapper profile do not work in api controller

Tags: c#, api, automapper, autofac, profile

I have two classes:

```
public class Parametro
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public int TipoDatoId { get; set; }
    public TipoDato TipoDato { get; set; }
}

public class ParametroCreateViewModel
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public int TipoDatoId { get; set; }
}
```

when I instate it in this way _mapper.Map  (model); I get the following error:

> Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below. Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type For no matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters
>   ParametroCreateViewModel-> Parametro(Destination member list) ProyectoTest.ServiciosCliente.Application.Parametros.Commands.AddFParametro.ParametroCreateViewModel-> Calidda.ServiciosCliente.Domain.Parametros.Parametro(Destination member list) Unmapped properties: Id

but when I try it this way if it works: 
**Mapper.Map < ParametroCreateViewModel,Parametro > (model);**

My autofac is the following :

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes().AssignableTo(typeof(Profile));
            builder.Register(c => new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                foreach (var profile in c.Resolve<IEnumerable<Profile>>())
                {
                    cfg.AddProfile(profile);
                }
            })).AsSelf().SingleInstance();
            builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<MapperConfiguration>().CreateMapper(c.Resolve)).As<IMapper>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

and my automapperconfig is:

```
public class AutoMapperConfig : Profile
{
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize((config) =>
        {

config.CreateMap<ParametroCreateViewModel, Parametro>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.Ignore()).ReverseMap();
        }
     }
   }
```

and declare my global.asax:

```
AutofacConfig.Register();
AutoMapperConfig.Initialize();
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like here is a combination of several issues. You should load certain assembly with profile classes and also register them as `Profile`. In your example the foreach loop didn't perform any iterations, because container didn't contain any registrations for `Profile`. To create a mapping you should use profile itself instead of static `Mapper` class. Static method `Initialize` was not called, so mapping was not created. Please consider this example:

```
public class AutoMapperConfig : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperConfig()
    {
        // Create mapping within profile in constructor
        CreateMap<ParametroCreateViewModel, Parametro>()
            // ignore both unmapped properties
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.TipoDato, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ReverseMap();
    }
}

[Test]
public void AutoMapperAutofacTest()
{
    // Arrange
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    // load certain assembly
    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(AutoMapperConfig)))
            .AssignableTo<Profile>()
            .As<Profile>(); // register as profile
    builder.Register(c => new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        foreach (var profile in c.Resolve<IEnumerable<Profile>>())
        {
            cfg.AddProfile(profile);
        }
    })).AsSelf().SingleInstance();
    builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<MapperConfiguration>().CreateMapper(c.Resolve)).As<IMapper>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    var container = builder.Build();

    var mapper = container.Resolve<IMapper>();

    var param = new Parametro();
    var viewModel = new ParametroCreateViewModel
    {
        Nombre = "Nombre",
        TipoDatoId = 1
    };

    // Act
    mapper.Map(viewModel, param);

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(param.TipoDatoId, 1);
    Assert.AreEqual(param.Nombre, "Nombre");
}
```

I have wrapped the example with test to make it reproducable. Hope it helps.

Comment: Happy to help=)